# eBPF - Cannot read argv and envp from tracepoint sys_enter_execve

Tags: linux, bpf, ebpf

I am learning BPF for my own fun, and I am having a hard time figuring out how to read `argv` and `envp` from the context passed to my eBPF program for sys_enter_execve

I will show my BPF program here and then explain in more details later what I am trying to accomplish.

Here's my code:

```c
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf_helpers.h>

struct
{
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, char[300]);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
} mymap SEC(".maps");

// Based on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_execve/format
struct execve_args {
    short common_type;
    char common_flags;
    char common_preempt_count;
    int common_pid;
    int __syscall_nr;
    char *filename;
    const char *const *argv;
    const char *const *envp;
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int bpf_prog(struct execve_args *ctx) {
  
  __u32 index = 0;
  __u64 *value = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&mymap, &index);

  // An array of length 300 is purely arbitrary here
  char fn[300];

    // null check for the value fetched from the map
    if (value){
     
      // trying here to get the first env var passed to the process
      // started with execve
      const char *const first_env_value = ctx->envp[0];

      // null check
      if (!first_env_value){
        return 0;
      }
      
      // trying to safely read the value pointed by first_env_value
      bpf_probe_read_user_str(fn, sizeof(fn), first_env_value);
      bpf_map_update_elem(&mymap, &index, fn, BPF_ANY);
      return 0;
    
    }

    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```

What I want, here, is to ultimately read the first environments variable referenced by `ctx->envp` and save it in the map.

Building the program succeeds, but it fails when I try to load it into the kernel:

```
8: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+15
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=300,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; const char *const first_env_value = ctx->envp[0];
9: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r6 +32)
; const char *const first_env_value = ctx->envp[0];
10: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)
R1 invalid mem access 'inv'
processed 10 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 0 peak_states 0 mark_read 0
```

I use bpf2go from Cilium project to load the BPF program into the kernel. And I use a Go program to read there BPF map.

Can someone give me some hints as to what am I doing wrong?

Maybe it is the double pointer that confuses me (const char *const *envp), maybe I misunderstand the `sys_enter_execve` system call and the tracepoint inputs, etc.

Any hint would be appreciated!

I'm not a kernel developer. I mostly code in Go and Python, but I really want to learn how to write BPF programs in pure C, just for the fun of it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR.** You are trying to read arbitrary kernel memory. You need to use [`bpf_probe_read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/BPF-HELPERS.7.html) for that.

---

Let's have a look at the error logs:

The invalid memory access is on a load from `r1`. The value in `r1` was loaded from memory using the address in `r6` as the base. According to the second line, the verifier associates type `ctx` to `r6`.

So `r6` points to your variable `ctx`. That variable is special (hence why the verifier has a special `ctx` type for it). Your BPF program is allowed to access memory pointed by that variable as long as its bounded (the exact bound depends on the program type).

```
8: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+15
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=300,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; const char *const first_env_value = ctx->envp[0];
9: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r6 +32)
; const char *const first_env_value = ctx->envp[0];
10: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r1 +0)
R1 invalid mem access 'inv'
```

However, the value you retrieve from `ctx->envp` (the value stored in `r1`) is not part of `ctx` and may point to arbitrary kernel memory. The BPF verifier thus can't ensure ahead-of-time the safety of that access and rejects your program.

You need to use a BPF helper, [`bpf_probe_read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/BPF-HELPERS.7.html), to access that memory. That helper will perform runtime checks to ensure the memory access is safe. If it's unsafe, it will return a negative error.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed. I have published an answer below with your suggestion. It works now! I have marked your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Also thanks for taking the time to explain the error logs. I admit I did not looked too much into them as I did not understand them a lot. Now it makes more sens. I just need to remove the rust from my assembly language knowledge :)

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped! The verifier's error logs can be a a bit intimidating at first, but it gets better with a little practice. It's mostly the same root causes all the time :-)

Comment: @pchaigno, _However, the value you retrieve from ctx->envp (the value stored in r1) is not part of ctx_ I don't quite understand this part. If `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_execve/format` reports `envp`, why it is not considered a part of ctx? Thanks.

Comment: Because it is a pointer, not a value. `envp` is a value pointed by `ctx`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks a lot @pchaigno, you were absolutely right. To show other people how I solved my problem, here is the solution I have, based on pchaigno answer.

```c
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <bpf_helpers.h>

struct
{
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, char[300]);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
} mymap SEC(".maps");

// Based on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_execve/format
struct execve_args {
    short common_type;
    char common_flags;
    char common_preempt_count;
    int common_pid;
    int __syscall_nr;
    char *filename;
    const char *const *argv;
    const char *const *envp;
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int bpf_prog(struct execve_args *ctx) {
  
  __u32 index = 0;

  // Here we reserve a pointer to the first env var
  char *first_env_var;

  // Here we attempt to read the value pointed by ctx->envp[0] and store it in *first_env_var
  long res = bpf_probe_read(&first_env_var, sizeof(first_env_var), &ctx->envp[2]);

  // For demo purposes, simply return from the program 
  // if there is an error with bpf_probe_read
  if (res != 0){
    return 0;
  }
  
  // Read the value pointed by the (now) safe pointer *first_env_var
  // and store the value in 'value'
  char value[300];
  bpf_probe_read_str(value, sizeof(value), first_env_var);

  // Copy the value to the map
  bpf_map_update_elem(&mymap, &index, &value, BPF_ANY);
      
    return 0;
}

char _license[] SEC("license") = "GPL";
```