# How to bpf_probe_read_str all ctx->argv elements in kernel space and forward it to the userspace?

Tags: c, system-calls, ebpf, execve, tracepoint

I am new to eBPF and currently trying to send all the executed commands with arguments in the userspace using a perf map.

I manage to send most of my data, but not the one accessed with `bpf_probe_read_str`. Print the output in console works, but i don't know where to look for to forward `ctx->argv` to the userspace after reading it from kernel.

Maybe am i supposed to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188440/ebpf-cannot-read-argv-and-envp-from-tracepoint-sys-enter-execve) but copy all argv item manually ?

My code is based on [liz's chapter 7 tuto](https://github.com/lizrice/learning-ebpf/tree/main/chapter7)

```
struct sys_enter_execve
{
    // ...
    char **argv;
};

struct data_t
{
    // ...
    char **argv;
};
SEC("tp/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int tp_sys_enter_execve(struct sys_enter_execve *ctx)
{
    struct data_t data = {};

    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ctx->argv); i++)
    {
        char *arg = NULL;
        bpf_probe_read_user_str(&arg, sizeof(arg),  &ctx->argv[i]);

        data.argv[i] = arg; // Lead to the below error
        // bpf_map_update_elem(&argv, &i, &arg, BPF_ANY); // Another solution that lead to infinite loop for the verifier
        bpf_printk("arg%d: %s ", i, arg); // Works and print the correct sting
    }

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &output, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &data, sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the error from `data.argv[i] = arg;`

```
42: (85) call bpf_probe_read_user_str#114     ; R0=scalar(smin=-4095,smax=8) fp-72=mmmmmmmm
; data.argv[i] = arg;
43: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r10 -72)       ; R1_w=scalar() R10=fp0 fp-72=mmmmmmmm
; data.argv[i] = arg;
44: (79) r2 = *(u64 *)(r10 -8)        ; R2_w=P0 R10=fp0 fp-8=00000000
; data.argv[i] = arg;
45: (7b) *(u64 *)(r2 +0) = r1
R2 invalid mem access 'scalar'
processed 43 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 0 total_states 3 peak_states 3 mark_read 3
Failed to load BPF object
```

I tried the alternantive solution to manually copy all args into an hashmap with `bpf_map_update_elem(&argv, &i, &arg, BPF_ANY);` but the verifier can't load the program and send the below error

```
62: (85) call bpf_trace_printk#6
; for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ctx->argv); i++)
infinite loop detected at insn 63
processed 97 insns (limit 1000000) max_states_per_insn 1 total_states 6 peak_states 6 mark_read 4
```

What did i miss in the documentation ?
Thanks ✌️

Answer (score 2):

So there were few confusion i had and it explain why i could not fix this problem. I'll give more details below.

I think the error `invalid mem access 'scalar'` means that the verifier can't determine the size of a char pointer to check that the size of all variables stay in 512 bytes. Basically to fix this was just to fix the size of my variable from `char **argv;` to `char[8][50]`. I have noticed that the length of `ctx->argv` was always 8 so i took this value. Then the second mistake was to make sure the value was safe using `bpf_probe_read` before `bpf_probe_read_str`

So the final code look like this.

```
struct sys_enter_execve
{
    // ...
    char **argv;
};

struct data_t
{
    // ...
    char argv[8][50]; // Fix the size here is critical for the verifier
};
SEC("tp/syscalls/sys_enter_execve")
int tp_sys_enter_execve(struct sys_enter_execve *ctx)
{
    struct data_t data = {};

    // ...

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ctx->argv); i++)
    {
        char *tmp;
        bpf_probe_read(&tmp, sizeof(tmp), &ctx->argv[i]);
        bpf_probe_read_str(data.argv[i], sizeof(data.argv[i]), tmp);
    }

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &output, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &data, sizeof(data));
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it could help for your code.

Happy coding ✌️